# Systematic process to find replacement fluorescent T5 lamp holder

Tags: fluorescent, lamp-tombstone

The goal is to replace a plastic T5 tombstones has melted. The side 'wings' fold-in so it can be 'dropped-into' the fixture.

[image]   [image]  [image]

There are approximately 100+ tombstones and one has melted. Is there a clever technique to identify a suitable replacement part?  Google & Amazon searches have not produced high confidence results.

## Update

Replacement part purchased and successfully deployed: [https://www.amazon.com/Leviton-13660-SWP-Fluorescent-Lampholder-Mounted/dp/B003AURQWW/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003AURQWW)

Next time I will purchase shunted, because I do not use single ended bulbs.

https://www.amazon.com/gp/offer-listing/B0036ZA9AW/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need a t5 tombstone, that looks like a tall one measure it and places like 1000 bulbs.com or other places have them, depending on quanties for less than a buck. Just make sure if shunted or non shunted you get the correct type, if you get non shunted you can always add a jumper if needed.

Comment: Good call: purchased the part from 1000bulbs via AMZN